# Railstutorial Chapter 9 User index test raised a failure after modify pagination

Tags: railstutorial.org

I'm just curious how its happen

After try to reduce number of user per page in pagination to 10 (default is 30 that I think is too long). My index test raised a failure just like this

```
1) Failure:
UsersIndexTest#test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links
[/home/ubuntu/workspace/contoh/test/integration/users_index_test.rb:17]:
Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/users/338193910"]", found 0..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

What i've changed is just the pagination parameter  [Listing 9.42](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#code-will_paginate_index_action)

```
@users = User.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
```

in app/controllers/users_controller.rb

and here is the line 17-20 in /users_index_test.rb

```
assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
unless user == @admin
assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete',
                                                method: :delete
```

Comment: It's expecting to find user 338193910, but now isn't. My guess is that in the pagination, user 338193910 is somewhere between 11 and 30 in the list. Try looking for a user you know will be in the first 10.

Comment: thank you for commenting Sir. But when i changed the parameter to global, as I mentioned below , I get green/successful test.. I'm still curious about it , but I consider that the solution is enough for me

Comment: and FYI my fixtures only set 34 users so those number is still mystery .

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't used the gem before. So that was just my best guess. I'll have to check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem because I changed this 
in my app/controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

to

```
def index
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end
```

Now i got the same error with the users_index_test

After some browsing and reading this article I came up with the following solution:

In the test/integration/users_index_test.rb I changed:

```
first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
```

to

```
first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 10)
```

The test is now successfull :)

Comment: Oh , I see now. The test don't use pagination parameter from user controller. So we have to re-declare it in our test. Thank you for clarifying this. Awesome job

Answer (score 1):

After trying some configuration

I've found that put the **per_page** parameter in global parameter is the solution

So, i put it in **app/controller/application_controller.rb** this line

```
WillPaginate.per_page = 10
```